Lipschitz continuity of solution operator of controlled ODE.
Consider the controlled ODE system
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}(t) &= f\bigl(t, x(t), u(t), b\bigr) \\
x(0) &= x_0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
where $x:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the searched for function, $u:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is the control function and $b\in\mathbb{R}^l$ are some parameters.
Consider the solution operator $S$ that maps from the initial data $(x_0, u, b)$ to the solution $x$. Is the solution operator $S$ jointly Lipschitz continuous and if so under which conditions?
EDIT 1
One has also to think about what is meant by jointly Lipschitz continuous. I do not know whether there is a definition of some Lipschitz continuity when we have several different input spaces.
EDIT 2
I assume $f$ to be jointly Lipschitz continuous in the same sense as stated here Continuity of a solution of a differential equation with respect to a time-dependent input? but now I am wondering if my solution operator is also jointly Lipschitz or at least locally Lipschitz continuous, in the sense that the solution $x$ does depend in such a way on $(x_0,u,b)$. Further I know that it is enough to just consider
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}(t) &= f\bigl(x(t), u(t)\bigr) \\
x(0) &= x_0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
as we are always able to rewrite a ODE in that way.
